# Does openGL 3.3 code run under 4.1

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, opengl-4

in my computer science course we're working with openGL this term. Our teacher said we need openGL 3.3 (also 3.3 for the shader language), but on my laptop is 4.1 already installed.

```
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NVCE
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Is there a way to downgrade openGL or will the code we're programming work on my version too?

I am using a kali linux (debian) laptop with a nvidia GPU by the way.

Comment: One thing to look out for is that, if you work on your computer, you might inadvertently use 4.0/4.1 features. Then if you submit class work, it would not work on a computer that only supports 3.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL 4.1 is completely backwards compatible with any 3.3 code. So yes, you should be able to run your 3.3 code.